# how to set table name as parameter in procedure oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

I have a procedure in Oracle which return all row that answer the SQL sentence. 
The procedure get 4 parameters which 3 of them use in-said the SQL sentence. Look down (the code). 
Only the parameter: in_table_name causes an error, **how can I move a table_name to SQL sentence by procedure ?** (I tried with "&", but it's doesn't work)

```
create or replace Procedure return_rows_EMPLOYEE (in_order in number, 
in_sorting in VARCHAR2, in_job in VARCHAR2, in_table_name in VARCHAR2, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) As
Begin
  if in_order = 1 THEN
     OPEN out_cursor for
     select * from &in_table_name
     WHERE EMPL_JOB_TITLE = in_job
     ORDER BY in_sorting ASC;
  else
     OPEN out_cursor for
     select * from &in_table_name
     WHERE EMPL_JOB_TITLE = in_job
     ORDER BY in_sorting DESC;
    END if;
End;
```

Comment: Use a dynamic query. you can't use table name as parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Rahul pointed out, you can not use table name as parameter. But i'd also add that you can't use table name as a `USING` parameter in an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` clause. You have to actually concatenate it in your query. Below is the (untested!) resulting query.

```
create or replace Procedure return_rows_EMPLOYEE (in_order in number, 
in_sorting in VARCHAR2, in_job in VARCHAR2, in_table_name in VARCHAR2, out_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) 
As
query varchar2(4000);
Begin
  if in_order = 1 THEN
     query := 
     'select * from ' || in_table_name ||
     ' WHERE EMPL_JOB_TITLE = :1
      ORDER BY :2 ASC';
  else
     OPEN out_cursor for
     query := 
     'select * from ' || in_table_name ||
     ' WHERE EMPL_JOB_TITLE = :1
      ORDER BY :2 DESC';
  end if;

  open out_cursor for query using in_job, in_sorting;
End;
```